How can I detect if a YouTube video is HDR using JavaScript?
I want to detect if the video which is played is hdr or not automatically.
YouTube Data API: I looked into the YouTube Data API v3 but found no explicit indicators for HDR content in the video metadata.
Client-Side Detection: I considered checking video properties via a  element in JavaScript, but it seems that browsers do not expose HDR-related properties.

I think you would have to access the actual video data for this.  I don't think there's an existing API.
